# I cannot browse the internet using a normal connection but can using Tor

Tags: networking, tor

Why can’t I using my normal connection but when I use Tor network it works?

I’m using mobile broadband (ppp).

I tried to ping `www.google.com` but the result was

```
mrahimi@CQ40:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Has my ISP banned me or is there some other problem?

I have disabled my UFW firewall but still have the same problem.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
```

I tried using the network proxy (using Chrome) and the internet worked normally, but when I use the normal connections I again have no connections. Does this mean I have been banned by my ISP?

Comment: Looks more like a DNS or firewall problem. What is the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and are you running a firewall ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen # Generated by NetworkManager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure DNS . Usually your DNS is provided by your router (192.168.0.0 ? )

### networkmanager

[image]

Comment: I not configure any DNS on my network manager and i'm using mobile broadband..

Comment: Try using the google dns servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (set them in network manager) https://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html

Comment: Can know why this happen? If you don't mind?

Comment: I am not sure, unless you manually configured your connection, something about your mobile broadband setting an IP abut not a DNS. I do not have the hardware / IP provider to test. Perhaps someone else will know and we can both learn.